# why angular Http Post Request throw error of JSon parse

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

```
CreateElement(){
        console.log(this.myForm.value)//Object { nomModule: "hfghfghfghgf", codeModule: "hgfhffhg", classNom: "" }
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/elements/create_Module';
        this.http.post<any>(url,{...this.myForm.value}).subscribe(
          (response:any) => {
            this.validationModule = response
            this.FetchAllModules()
          },
          (errors:any) => {
            console.log(errors)
            this.validationModule = {...errors.error}
            //console.error('Error:', this.validationModule);
          }
        )
      }
```

i got this error

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/elements/create_Module", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/elements/create_Module", error: {…} }
    error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "Element is saved succefully" }
    error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    text: "Element is saved succefully"
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
     }
    message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/elements/create_Module"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "http://localhost:8080/elements/create_Module"
```

**i m expecting to work fine but i really dont know the reason i test it with postman and it works**

Comment: Can you share the body of the request data. Might not be valid json that is received.

Comment: can you share `FetchAllModules()`, you might be using `JSON.parse` here with invalid json

Answer (score 0):

I can`t see your header attached with POST request, but it is showing in the error. How do you pass it?